# How to hightlight all ancestor menu items of a child page NOT displayed in menu

Tags: functions, menus, sub-menu, child-pages

Here's the situation: In my main navigation menu I have something that looks like this:

- Work with Me

  - Latest Projects

Where the Latest Projects page is a child page and sub menu item of the Work With Me page *and* both are displayed in the main navigation.

However, I have multiple Project pages that are only child pages of Latest Projects. I decided not to display them in the menu as sub menu items as the list would be too long.

So, what I would like to have happen is when a viewer is on one of the Project pages, *both* the Latest Projects and Work With Me menu items are active (highlighted).

I found this code to add to my functions.php file. It works, but it only highlights the Latest Projects menu item (not the Work With Me item).

```
<?php //in functions.php
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'highlight_portfolio', 12, 2);
function highlight_portfolio($classes, $item) {
    $parent = get_post_ancestors();
    $parent_ID = $parent[0];
    if ($parent_ID == $item->object_id) {
        array_push($classes, 'current-menu-ancestor');
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

How can I modify this code to include all ancestor menu items? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking against just one parent item.

Instead, you might check against all of the parents

```
<?php //in functions.php
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'highlight_portfolio', 12, 2);
function highlight_portfolio($classes, $item) {
    $parents = get_post_ancestors();
    if ( 0 < count($parents) ) {
        if ( in_array( $item->object_id, $parents ) {
            array_push( $classes, 'current-menu-ancestor' );
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Notice in your code

```
$parent_ID = $parent[0];
```

That only grabs the first parent id in the list returned. Using in_array checks to see if it matches any of the ancestors.